# Laravel migration foreign keys references to a primary key with two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.3 and MySQL.

How can I add in Laravel foreign keys references to a primary key with two columns?

Below are my migration scripts *(under the `database/migrations/` directory)*:

primary key with two columns

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('X', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('a')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('b')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['a', 'b']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and in another,

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('Y', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('k');
        $table->foreign('c')->references(['a', 'b'])->on('X')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

However, it doesn't work so: how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Use ***`Schema::table()`*** instead of ***`Schema::create()`*** when adding *foreign key constraints* to your database.

Below, snippets illustrating the fix:

```
// File name: 2016_09_28_create_x_table.php
public function up()
{
    // Create table X
    Schema::create('X', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('a')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('b')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['a', 'b']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


// File name: 2016_09_28_create_y_with_foreignkey_table.php
public function up()
{
    // Create table Y
    Schema::create('Y', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('k');
        $table->integer('c')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Add Foreign key
    Schema::table('Y', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('c')->references('a')->on('X')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

*Remember* ***`unsigned()`*** *should be applied on the* ***`c`***.

Comment: I have done as you wrote, but I didn't get it work. Have you ever tried this approach? Any ideas? Many Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'MYDB.#sql-552_2c' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `Y` add constraint `y_id_c_foreign` foreign key (`c`) references `X` (  
  `a`, `b`) on delete cascade)

Comment: And also I got another error                                                                                              
  [PDOException]                                                                              
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'MYDB.#sql-552_2c' (errno: 150)  , I have done all this migration from zero, I mean removing the db and creating a new one. After that, I did php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: Try the last update I've submitted; ***`$table->foreign('c')->references('a')->on('X')->onDelete('cascade');`***; it works without any error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124501/discussion-between-nyedidikeke-and-ackuser).

Comment: It works with the last modification, however it is doing a reference to only one attribute in the primary key. Then, obviously the integrity is not the same

Comment: +1 for the separation in the logic between table and create was very helpful and he gave me the idea to get it working with the rest, anyway is not the final solution that I would choose because it is doing a reference to only one attribute in the primary key.

Comment: working thanks , just to be sure add make the string foreign key index, beside the @nyedidikeke advice

Answer (score 1):

```
Foreign key should be set for 2 columns. foreign() should get also array

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('X', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('a')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('b')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['a', 'b']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('Y', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('k');
        $table->integer('a');
        $table->integer('b');
        $table->foreign(['a', 'b'])->references(['a', 'b'])->on('X')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}`
```

Comment: Can you add  some explanation for how this code answers the question? It appears to be completely identical to the code provided in the question. Is there something different here? If so, can you explain what you changed and how this adds foreign key references to a primary key?

Comment: Foreign key on second table is related to 2 fields

Comment: Thanks for clarifying here, but could you [edit] your answer and add the explanation there? High quality answers improve the SO for all programmers looking for answers, plus there may be more upvotes in your future when your answers are clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way that I found to simulate composite keys and FK pointing to composite keys working in Laravel 5.3 - I miss a more compacted solution in Laravel.

Anyway, here is my code

```
// File name: 2016_09_28_create_x_table.php
public function up()
{
    // Create table X
    Schema::create('X', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('j');
        $table->integer('a')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('b')->unsigned();
        $table->unique(['a', 'b']);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


// File name: 2016_09_28_create_y_with_foreignkey_table.php
public function up()
{
    // Create table Y
    Schema::create('Y', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('k');
        $table->integer('c')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Add Foreign key
    Schema::table('Y', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('c')->references('j')->on('X')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```